# Existence of step from N to P position in compound game using Sprague-Grundy function

Tags: game-theory

Given $3$ piles containing $\{27, 24, 36\}$ pebbles in each. Players can take
$\{1,4,5\} , \{2,3,7\}, \{3,4,6\}$ from first, second and third piles respectively.

---

**I need to show that [Sprague-Grundy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sprague%E2%80%93Grundy_theorem) function gives me the winning and loosing position of the compound game.**

I started by drawing each sequence separately and observing the pattern. I found this repetitive Sprague-Grundy values from $0$ to $m,n,k$ as follows:

$\text{pile #1} \{0,1,0,1,4,5,4,5\}$, $\text{pile #2}\{0,0,2,2,4\}$, and  $\text{pile #3}\{0,0,0,3,3,3,6,6,6\}$.

So the initial Sprague-Grundy is $g(27,24,36) =$ g1(27)^g2(24)^g_3(36) = 1^3^0 = 6, which is a losing position. From this state $(27,24,36)$ I can move to the winning position $(27,22,36)$ because it is a movable step and its Sprague-Grundy value is 1^1^0 = 0; At this point I know why result $0$ of xor gives winning position in nim game, there is no restriction to number of pebbles
 to remove, but in take away game there is restriction.

---

Why even with this restriction there exists a move from loosing position(N) to winning position(P) in compound subtraction game?

Comment: I haven't been introduced to "Sprague-Grandie". Could you at least give a reference (I would give you a reference if had to make development about the not so well known von Hindenburg - Nekrasov - Yamamoto formula)

Comment: Sure [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sprague%E2%80%93Grundy_theorem)

Comment: It is the Sprague-Grundy theorem, as in the Wikipedia page you cite.

Answer (score 1):

The point of the Sprague-Grundy theorem is to calculate the nimber, the number of stones in a pile of unrestricted nim, that corresponds to a pile of stones in your game.  The nimber of a position is the minimum nimber that you cannot move to from that position.  In regular nim, a pile of six stones can move to $0,1,2,3,4,5$, so the nimber is $*6$.  Taking your second game, a pile of $0$ or $1$ stones is $0$ because you can't move at all.  A pile of $2$ stones is $*1$ because you can move to $0$ but not to $*1$.  A pile of $3$ stones is $*1$ as well because both moves are to $0$.  A pile of $4$ stones is $*2$ because you can move to $0$ by taking $3$ or to $*1$ by taking $2$.  You need to recalculate all of your nimber values.

Assuming the values of the three piles were $*1,*3,0$, the value of the group of three piles would be $XOR(*1,*3,0)=*2,$ not $*6$.  You could reach a winning position by moving from $*3$ to $*1$ because $XOR(*1,*1,0)=0$.  You are guaranteed to be able to do this because $*3$ must be able to move to any of $0,*1,*2$.  Then if your opponent takes one $*1$ to $0$ you take the other.  Otherwise he must take the $0$ to some nimber which you can take back to $0$ or he can take one of the $*1$s to a higher nimber and you can take it back.